# MVC Forms Authentication and Session, Authorize Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, cookies

I have a MVC project that I'm using Forms Authentication, and I had to implement Roles for certain pages, so I got this in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "")
    {
        return;
    }

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket;
    try
    {
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(';');

    if (Context.User != null)
    {
        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
    }
}
```

And I save the user roles when I log in my model:

```
//After checking login/password
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
if (cookie == null) 
{ 
    cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 
}

string userRoles = null;
if (users[i].PerfilID == UserRanks.Admin)
{
    userRoles = "Admin;Users";
}
else
{
    userRoles = "Users";
}

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(0,
    users[i].Name,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    false,
    userRoles,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
);
cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = users[i].UserID;
HttpContext.Current.Session["LastLogin"] = users[i].LastLogin;
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, userRoles.Split(';'));
```

To retrieve the values of the session variables, I have a static property:

```
public static int UserID 
{
    get 
    {
        object sessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
        if (sessionData == null)
        {
            //I had something here...
            return 0;
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(sessionData);
    }
    private set { }
}
```

Before I implemented roles authorization, I used to save the UserID in the cookie userData, and if the UserID in the session, when requested, was null, I'd retrieve it from the cookie instead (and set it to the session again).
Now the userData is being used to the roles management and I'm having issues with the session dropping faster than the cookie expiration, and I have users logged in which I can't retrieve their UserIDs and thus fails for all operations.

So I have to put a checker in each controller function such as:

```
if (MyUser.Session.UserID == 0)
{
    //redirect to Login
}
```

...which defeats the whole purpose of using `[Authorize]` I guess.
Is there a better way to handle login expiration and session variables like this?

I thought about using JSON or some other format and save a bunch of userData in the cookie, but I'd like something simpler, if possible.

Also, I'm doing this in the login:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, userRoles.Split(';'));
```

Which seems to be about the same the AuthenticateRequest does (I got that part from elsewhere, seemed to be the recommended way to handle member roles), but it doesn't work like it should. The user always gets redirected out on the `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` or even the `[Authorize]` only functions if I leave only that (and remove the `global.asax` part). Why?

Comment: Why are you doing all that extra forms authentication mucking about?  Roles management is built right in, and you don't have to do any extra work, other than configuring it in web.config

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I googled around because I wanted something really simple for role management, but this was the simplest I could find. Other solutions involved having a database pre-configured and/or entity framework, which I don't have. If there is some simpler way to just assign a user some specific role(s) when he log-in and then just using the regular `[Authorize(Roles="")]` attribute, please share!

Comment: How are you doing logins if you don't have a database?  What is your UserID?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I do have a database, but I'm not using Entity or NHibernate, and there's a bunch of rules I need to check/apply per user and logins, so I needed something that I could put in my login code and make it work somehow. It's a project that uses 2 other projects (and their DBs), so logins/users are really really messy, and so are the rules/checks for them...